# Manage Large amount of Master Data in Xamarin Forms (IOS and UWP)

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, uwp

In our application we have lot of master data(calculation data encrypted) and metadata(for UI). Those data will be pushed to SQLite database from JSON FILE when the app gets started. We are looking for some other solution than JSON. Could you provide some suggestion on it?

I just want to migrate the data(NOT FROM JSON FILE) to database for the first time when app gets started

Comment: Can you tell us, why do you want to change `json` to something else? What's wrong with it?

Comment: You want to use another data storage method to replace JSON file, Right?

Comment: We have lot of modules to be developed and all developer does these changes in metadata which has about 20 Json files. We have same meta data in excel(Master copy) and we convert it to json and update in the solution file. All developers face conflicts between Json and Excel file daily. Do we have any mechanism to automate it or better way to do it. Thanks for your help

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT Yes, Also need to handle it more efficiently with out conflicts when most of them develops it.

Comment: @BaluPrasath, For your requirement, The better way is using web service manage the metadata. and use client push edit data.